# CDH spark steaming consumer kerberos kafka

Tags: pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kerberos, cloudera-cdh

Does any one tried to use spark-steaming(pyspark) as consumer for kerberos KAFKA in CDH ?

I search the CDH and just find some example about Scala.

Does it means CDH does not support this ?

Anyone can help on this ???

Answer (score 0):

CDH supports Pyspark based Structured Streaming API to connect Kerberos-secured Kafka cluster as well. Even I found it hard to find example code . You can refer below sample code which well tested and implemented in CDH prod environment .

**Note** : Points to consider in below sample code .

Adjust packages version based on your environment .

Mention right JAAS,Keytab file location in spark submit command and config parameters in code.

This code has been given as an example to read Kerberos enabled Kafka cluster topic and writing into HDFS location.

```
spark/bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.2.0,com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:3.2.0  --conf spark.ui.port=4055 --files /home/path/spark_jaas,/home/bdpda/bdpda.headless.keytab --conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/bdpda/spark_jaas" --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/bdpda/spark_jaas" pysparkstructurestreaming.py
```

Pyspark code: pysparkstructurestreaming.py

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
import time

#  Spark Streaming context :

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('PythonStreamingDirectKafkaWordCount').getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 20)

#  Kafka Topic Details :

KAFKA_TOPIC_NAME_CONS = "topic_name"
KAFKA_OUTPUT_TOPIC_NAME_CONS = "topic_to_hdfs"
KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONS = 'kafka_server:9093'

#  Creating  readstream DataFrame :

df = spark.readStream \
     .format("kafka") \
     .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONS) \
     .option("subscribe", KAFKA_TOPIC_NAME_CONS) \
     .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
     .option("kafka.security.protocol","SASL_SSL")\
     .option("kafka.client.id" ,"Clinet_id")\
     .option("kafka.sasl.kerberos.service.name","kafka")\
     .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.location", "/home/path/kafka_trust.jks") \
     .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.password", "password_rd") \
     .option("kafka.sasl.kerberos.keytab","/home/path.keytab") \
     .option("kafka.sasl.kerberos.principal","path") \
     .load()

df1 = df.selectExpr( "CAST(value AS STRING)")

#  Creating  Writestream DataFrame :

df1.writeStream \
   .option("path","target_directory") \
   .format("csv") \
   .option("checkpointLocation","chkpint_directory") \
   .outputMode("append") \
   .start()

ssc.awaitTermination()
```